# Dealing with Browser Debug Inconsistency in Chrome: Discrepancy between 'userData' in Application Tab and 'undefined' in Networks Tab

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, web

How can I ensure a consistent developer experience in Chrome when encountering a discrepancy between the presence of 'userData' in the Application tab and its undefined value in the Networks tab, even though the cursor is positioned within the corresponding if statement during debugging?

[image]

[image]